# Database handle with perl always undefined

Tags: perl, cgi, dbi

I am having issues getting a simple DBI connection using perl to work.

I put a place checker to see if the database handle is undefined and it always comes out undefined. Are there any blatant errors? I'm assured that the info I enter is correct, as I'm using it in a php script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use warnings;
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";

use DBI;

# Connecting to the database
# Replace DATABASENAME with the name of the database,
# HOSTNAME with the hostname/ip address of the MySQL server.
$drh = DBI->install_driver("mysql");
$dsn =   "DBI:mysql:database=db_name;host=host_name";
$dbh = DBI->connect($dsn,"username","password");
if(defined $dbh)
{
    print "Yes<br />";
}
else
{
    print "No<br />";
 }

 # Select the data and display to the browser

   $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer");
   $sth->execute();
   while (my $ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
   print "Found a row: id = $ref->{'cid'}";
}

$sth->finish();

# Disconnect from the database.

$dbh->disconnect();
```

Comment: What happens if you `connect()` with `{ RaiseError => 1 }` ?

Comment: `$drh = DBI->install_driver("mysql");` is useless

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An error occured if `connect` returned undef. Throw some error handling in there.
It might give you some useful information.

```
$dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pw)
   or die "Unable to connect: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

Comment: When I add the following or die to the code it does not print the statement afterwards? I have feeling something is messed up with perl, but wouldn't know where to start. `$dbh = DBI->connect($dsn,"username","pw") or die "Unable to connect: $DBI::errstr\n";
print "why";`

Comment: It's unlikely that the problem is with perl.  Can you manually connect to the database? Are all you parameters you're sending correct? Add a 'use strict' to your code too.

Comment: I ran your code, with the added 'die' statement, on my machine and received an error.

Comment: The use strict helped determine the issue. It turns out it was evaluating part of the variables in the database handle and making those single quotes prevented that! Thanks!

Comment: Great.  You should always use 'use strict'. It will save you a lot of headaches.